# how can i know the number of elements in array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory-management, dynamic

i run the following code but it kept printing "4"

> why its printing "4" and not "12"? and can I use malloc and then sizeof?(if i can then how)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr1[3]={1,2,3};
    int *arr2=arr1,i;
    printf("%d",sizeof(arr2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check out this link on how to [determine the size of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

Answer (score 8):

[**Pointers are not arrays**](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/practdiff.html). `arr2` is a pointer to `int`. `sizeof(arr2)` will return size of pointer. To print size of an array, the operand of `sizeof` must be of an array type:

```
printf("%u",sizeof(arr1));
```

> can I use `malloc` and then `sizeof`?

No. There is no portable way to find out the size of a malloc'ed block. `malloc` returns pointer to the allocated memory. `sizeof` that pointer will return size of the pointer itself. But you should note that, there is no need to use `sizeof` when you allocate memory dynamically. In this case you already know the size of array. (In case of `char` array use `strlen`).

Further reading: [c-faq: Why doesn't `sizeof` tell me the size of the block of memory pointed to by a pointer?](http://www.c-faq.com/malloc/sizeof.html)

Answer (score 6):

`arr2` is a pointer and you are printing `sizeof(pointer)`

`sizeof(arr1)` will give you sizeof array which might give you 12.(Given your integer is 4 bytes)

Answer (score 6):

```
sizeof(arr2)
```

would print the size of pointer as it's a `int*`. However, if you try `sizeof(arr1)`, it would print

```
sizeof(element_type) * array_size
```

i.e *size of array*. Remember that it's not taking into account how many elements are there in array. It would just consider how many elements can array store.

Answer (score 3):

It's printing 4 because `arr2` is a pointer, and the size of a pointer is 4 bytes in 32bit architectures. You can't know the size of a dynamically allocated array ( array allocated with malloc ) given just a pointer to it.